# Accessing to the lastly executed command and modify it before executing in VIM

Tags: vim

Scenario.
Imagine, that I want to search replace something.

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

Now, imagine that I made a mistype and executed the command

```
:%s/fop/bar/g
```

Every vim user knows than `@:`  executes the last command, what if I want to modify last command and then - execute?

As an extended question, is it possible to navigate through the history like does `q:` and then select the command and modify it before executing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recall the previous command-line via `<Up>` in command-line mode, and then do inline editing, switching to the *command-line window* (with full Vim commands) via `<C-F>` if necessary. Or just do `q:k`, which is equivalent.

Note that you cannot directly modify `@:`, because it is a *read-only* register.

Comment: Thank you Ingo. You probably does mean `q:k` command. Also I don't understand <C-F>, if it's pressing Control+F in command mode , then it's not working